# Office 2016 or 2019 installation issue with office 365

Tags: microsoft-office

I've got Lenovo IdeaPad S145 with pre-installed office 365 with a 1 year license, I've activate that and worked with it for a while, but found that outlook isn't working properly with me, so decided to install office 2016 or 2019.
Uninstalled first the 365 and then installed the 2016, but everytime trying to open it found that 365 is loading ad opening with me instead of the 2016.
So Uninstalled 2016,and made sure that there's no office installed and then installed 2019 and same thing is happening again. 
Please tell me how to solve this issue please as I can't find a solution for it.

Comment: What precisely isn't working in Outlook 365 _(I've been using it for years without issue)_, as that's the most up-to-date version.  Also, it's cheaper to run Office 365 than it is to buy a standalone Office version over 4 years, coupled with the benefits of an always up-to-date Office install and free OneDrive storage _(cheaper subscription prices can be bought from retailers, rather than directly through Microsoft, esp if a student or military - or if an employer has a VLA for Office)_

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but actually it's my work email which is handling large attachments and since it's communicating on the cloud it hangs a lot beside its too slow compared to the standalone office

Comment: I think you may be confusing products... **Office 365 _is_ a [standalone version](https://account.microsoft.com/services/office/install) of Office**, it's simply subscription-based at the same price as prior cyclic versions of Office if spread over 3 - 4 years.  It sounds like you're using the Outlook _online_ app from the Windows Store and have not physically installed Office 365... [physically install it](https://account.microsoft.com/services/office/install) and you shouldn't have the issue you're currently experiencing.

Comment: Actually it came pre installed on the laptop and I've worked with it for like 3 days, but when it was getting too much emails with a lot of attachments, it started hanging and freezing and that's why I thought of getting office 2019, so my question how to make office 2019 work normally and not loading the 365 everytime I open any of the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the version you installed (Programs and Features). Now restart and remove the Office App(s) - Start, Settings, Apps. Once the built-in version has been removed, restart and install your own version. This works for all our new client computers with Office pre-installed.

Comment: Have already done this but even after installing the standome version, and when loading the outlook it shows and open to me the outlook 365 not the 2019 version. Which is my problem now, how come I Uninstaller the 365 version and it still load when opening the 2019 version!!

Comment: Office 2019 is pretty much a standalone version and not an advance on Office 2016 / 365 which is constantly being updated.  You might consider just using Office 2016 / 365 to get better results

Comment: Office 2016 & Office 365 are not the same products... Office 2016 is akin to Office 2019, but unlike 2016 or 2019, Office 365 is continually updated, analogous to how Microsoft has approached Windows 10.  Office 365 **_is_** a standalone version of Office and it installs to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root`.  It seems there may be some confusion between Windows Store Office Apps _(which are not full-featured, standalone versions of Office products)_ and the [standalone installer for Office 365](https://account.microsoft.com/services/office/install) - these are not the same things.

Comment: When I Uninstaller the 365 and after rebooting I cheched that path and deleted the folder and then installed the 2019, so my question is how come after doing all this and when loading any of the apps from office 2019 I found that 365 is loading with me again.

Comment: I suggest you stick with Office 2016 as it is the better choice